# URL manipulation with rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have URLs like these:

```
http://hi.com/id1-tag1-tag2-tag3.jpg
http://hi.com/id2-tag1.jpg
http://hi.com/id3-tag1=tag2-tag3-tag4-tag5.jpg
```

I need a rewrite rule so that it will drop all the tags and then format the URL so that it's

```
http://hi.com/id1.jpg
http://hi.com/id2.jpg
http://hi.com/id3.jpg
```

id will always be a unique identifer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-.+?\.jpg$ /$1.jpg [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hmm thanks but not sure that did it.

http://acme.com/test.jpg brings up the image but http://acme.com/test-234-234.jpg didn't

Comment: I tested this rule with `/test-234-234.jpg` and it redirected it to `/test.jpg`. Make sure this is your **very first rule**.

Comment: possible to rewrite but not actually rewrite the URL that shows in the  browser?

Comment: Didn't understand your comment, can you clarify?

Comment: If I type http://acme.com/test-234-234.jpg into the address bar in the browser, the server will rewrite the URL and the address bar will change to http://acme.com/test.jpg.  Is is possible to prevent this?